# Ajax remove link on Dropzone Laravel POST data empty result

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone

I created multiple upload with Dropzone, and added remove link with ajax request but when I did `echo json_encode($_POST);` here the **POST** data 
result was empty. Anyone have any solution ?

here is my following code :

```
var token = $('[name=_token').val();
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var imageUpload= new Dropzone(".dropzone",{
        url: "{{ route('saveImages') }}",
        maxFilesize: 2,
        method:"post",
        acceptedFiles:"image/*",
        paramName:"image",
        dictInvalidFileType:"Type file ini tidak dizinkan",
        addRemoveLinks:true,
        headers : {
            'X-CSRF-Token' : token
        }
    });

    //Event ketika Memulai mengupload
    imageUpload.on("sending",function(file, xhr, formData){
        var token_upload = 1337;
        formData.append("token_upload" , token_upload);
    });

    imageUpload.on("removedfile",function(formData){
        $.ajax({
            data    : { "token_upload":1337 },
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "{{ route('removeImages') }}",
            cache   : false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', "{{ csrf_token() }}");
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log("Foto terhapus");
            },
            error: function()
            {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `contentType: false` instructs jQuery not to send a Content-Type header at all, but PHP _needs_ a correct one to be set, otherwise it will not populate $_POST to begin with.

Comment: dump result still empty ... : {attributes: {}, request: {}, query: {}, server: {}, files: {}, cookies: {}, headers: {}}
attributes
:
{}
cookies
:
{}
files
:
{}
headers
:
{}
query
:
{}
request
:
{}
server
:
{}

Comment: Did you update your code regarding the Content-Type? Your callback function gets a parameter `formData` passed, but you are not doing anything with that … is that on purpose?

Comment: i've been try to post with `data: { "cuk": "woi" }`still didn't work  , look : https://postimg.cc/RqLmLPCp